# Idiosyncracy or Idiosyncrasy?

Tags: spelling, transatlantic-differences

Idiosyncracy is the way I've always spelt this, but 'idiosyncrasy' appears to be all but ubiquitous. Is this a UK-USA difference, or is the -cracy ending really incorrect?

Comment: It does not appear to be a UK/USA difference; the -crasy spelling is more common in both [US English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=idiosyncrasy%2Cidiosyncracy&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cidiosyncrasy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cidiosyncracy%3B%2Cc0) and [British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=idiosyncrasy%2Cidiosyncracy&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cidiosyncrasy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cidiosyncracy%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: These are easily found questions. Do they merit being asked here>

Comment: @Lambie: [Probably](//meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/65/ask-even-if-the-answer-exists-online).

Answer (score 2):

Most dictionaries do not list idiosyncracy. [TFD's entry for it](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/idiosyncracy) redirects to -crasy. [Its entry for colour](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/colour) does not. Same with [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suggestions/idiosyncracy), and [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/idiosyncracy) mentions that it's commonly considered a misspelling and, when listed in dictionaries, is only found under -crasy.

So, for practical purposes, it's just an error, not a trans-Atlantic difference.